# How to find driver causing "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software"?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

For the second time in about a week I got a "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software" popup after entering my password on the lock screen.

I had been away for 45 minutes, the system locked itself in the meantime.

**How can I find the driver that may cause this?**

Note that there's no additional info in the popup:

[image]

There is nothing in the Security Event log.
There are these errors in the Application Event log happening *during my absence*:

```
19:30:01 VSS Event ID 8194
         Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error querying for the IVssWriterCallback interface.
         hr = 0x80070005, Access is denied.
         This is often caused by incorrect security settings in either the writer or requestor process. 
         Operation: Gathering Writer Data
         Context:
           Writer Class Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
           Writer Name: System Writer
           Writer Instance ID: {a76e4df1-e62e-4f3e-9075-c77295c9ecdc}
19:30:01 VSS Event ID 8194 Idem
19:30:46 VSS Event ID 8194 Idem
         (and then at 19:41:09 the 8224 information message 'The VSS service is shutting down due to idle timeout.)
19:41:37 C:\Program Files\Dell\DellDataVault\DDVDataCollector.exe Application event ID 1000
         Faulting application name: DDVDataCollector.exe, version: 5.2.7.93, time stamp: 0x5bce2506
         Faulting module name: DDVDataCollector.exe, version: 5.2.7.93, time stamp: 0x5bce2506
         Exception code: 0xc0000409
         Fault offset: 0x00000000001cd3cb
         Faulting process id: 0xe34
         Faulting application start time: 0x01d4f4797e0833c9
         Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Dell\DellDataVault\DDVDataCollector.exe
         Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Dell\DellDataVault\DDVDataCollector.exe
         Report Id: 2afed137-4f0a-47f9-b67a-5a49814e3dbd
         Faulting package full name: 
         Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

[image]

The system event log shows three DistributedCOM events 10016 around 19:31:50:

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
to the user DESKTOP-COV1MII\JanDoggen SID (S-1-5-21-3973335050-762844696-57333725-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). 
This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

I recently investigated this DCOM error in another context and this is [expected and by design](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022522/dcom-event-id-10016-is-logged-in-windows-10-windows-server).

Cloudberry Backup ran a short incremental backup of my data drive D: from 19:30:01 to 19:31:34

Updates in the last two weeks:

- Notepad++ 7.6.6
- Dell SupportAssist 3.2.0.90
- Adobe Flash Player 32.0.0.171
- FireFox 66.0.3

From all this the primary suspect is DDVDataCollector.exe which seems to belong to the Dell SupportAssist 'Data Vault', but as my title question says: how can I check this (other than disabling all this Dell stuff and waiting a month or more)?

Comment: Having previously researched this particular application, I can say that it's attempting to install something that while properly signed, was signed with a certificate that is now expired.  I would simply uninstall the software, my past experience with OEM software has proven, OEM software not often kept updated and has been indirectly used in malware attacks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The place in the Event Viewer to look for applicable error messages for certificate
errors for drivers, is in the branch of
*Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > CodeIntegrity*.

For the poster, the relevant error message was one level deeper, in the sub-folder
*Operational*.

Comment: Thanks, the culprit was \Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll  I've uninstalled Bonjour, since I use no Apple stuff (it's surprising on how many Windows systems I've seen this thing)

Comment: The google query [Bonjour site:superuser.com](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hl=en-FR&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=Bonjour+site%3Asuperuser.com&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=1) has currently 1,880 posts as result (!).

Comment: The majority of those results have nothing to do with the author's problem

Comment: @Ramhound: This was to show how troublesome it is, no other motive.